TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.10.0)
I am trying to complete SpeedRunEthereum's second challenge 'TokenVendor' and I get this error when I firstly modified YourToken.sol, Vendor.sol, packages/hardhat/deploy/01_deploy_vendor.ts and packages/nextjs/app/token-vendor/page.tsx. When I run the command yarn deploy after I did the first steps of the challenge it gives this error "TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.10.0)"
My 01_deploy_vendor.ts is
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types";
import { Contract } from "ethers";

/**
 * Deploys a contract named "Vendor" using the deployer account and
 * constructor arguments set to the deployer address
 *
 * @param hre HardhatRuntimeEnvironment object.
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const deployVendor: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  /*
    On localhost, the deployer account is the one that comes with Hardhat, which is already funded.

    When deploying to live networks (e.g `yarn deploy --network goerli`), the deployer account
    should have sufficient balance to pay for the gas fees for contract creation.

    You can generate a random account with `yarn generate` which will fill DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY
    with a random private key in the .env file (then used on hardhat.config.ts)
    You can run the `yarn account` command to check your balance in every network.
  */
  // Deploy Vendor
  const { deployer } = await hre.getNamedAccounts();
  const { deploy } = hre.deployments;
  const yourToken = await hre.ethers.getContract<Contract>("YourToken", deployer);
  const yourTokenAddress = await yourToken.getAddress();
  await deploy("Vendor", {
    from: deployer,
    // Contract constructor arguments
    args: [yourTokenAddress],
    log: true,
    // autoMine: can be passed to the deploy function to make the deployment process faster on local networks by
    // automatically mining the contract deployment transaction. There is no effect on live networks.
    autoMine: true,
  });
  const vendor = await hre.ethers.getContract<Contract>("Vendor", deployer);
  const vendorAddress = await vendor.getAddress();
  // Transfer tokens to Vendor
  await yourToken.transfer(
    vendor.address,
    hre.ethers.parseEther("1000")
  );
  // Transfer contract ownership to your frontend address
  await vendor.transferOwnership("msg.sender");
};

export default deployVendor;

// Tags are useful if you have multiple deploy files and only want to run one of them.
// e.g. yarn deploy --tags Vendor
deployVendor.tags = ["Vendor"];

My packages/nextjs/app/token-vendor/page.tsx is
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { formatEther } from "viem";
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";
import { AddressInput, IntegerInput } from "~~/components/scaffold-eth";
import { useDeployedContractInfo, useScaffoldReadContract, useScaffoldWriteContract } from "~~/hooks/scaffold-eth";
import { useWatchBalance } from "~~/hooks/scaffold-eth/useWatchBalance";
import { getTokenPrice, multiplyTo1e18 } from "~~/utils/scaffold-eth/priceInWei";

const TokenVendor: NextPage = () => {
  const [toAddress, setToAddress] = useState("");
  const [tokensToSend, setTokensToSend] = useState("");
  const [tokensToBuy, setTokensToBuy] = useState<string | bigint>("");
  const [isApproved, setIsApproved] = useState(false);
  const [tokensToSell, setTokensToSell] = useState<string>("");

  const { address } = useAccount();
  const { data: yourTokenSymbol } = useScaffoldReadContract({
    contractName: "YourToken",
    functionName: "symbol",
  });

  const { data: yourTokenBalance } = useScaffoldReadContract({
    contractName: "YourToken",
    functionName: "balanceOf",
    args: [address],
  });

  const { data: vendorContractData } = useDeployedContractInfo("Vendor");
  const { writeContractAsync: writeVendorAsync } = useScaffoldWriteContract("Vendor");
  const { writeContractAsync: writeYourTokenAsync } = useScaffoldWriteContract("YourToken");

  // const { data: vendorTokenBalance } = useScaffoldReadContract({
  //   contractName: "YourToken",
  //   functionName: "balanceOf",
  //   args: [vendorContractData?.address],
  // });

  // const { data: vendorEthBalance } = useWatchBalance({ address: vendorContractData?.address });

  // const { data: tokensPerEth } = useScaffoldReadContract({
  //   contractName: "Vendor",
  //   functionName: "tokensPerEth",
  // });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-center flex-col flex-grow pt-10">
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center bg-base-100 shadow-lg shadow-secondary border-8 border-secondary rounded-xl p-6 mt-24 w-full max-w-lg">
          <div className="text-xl">
            Your token balance:{" "}
            <div className="inline-flex items-center justify-center">
              {parseFloat(formatEther(yourTokenBalance || 0n)).toFixed(4)}
              <span className="font-bold ml-1">{yourTokenSymbol}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Vendor Balances */}
          {/* <hr className="w-full border-secondary my-3" />
          <div>
            Vendor token balance:{" "}
            <div className="inline-flex items-center justify-center">
              {Number(formatEther(vendorTokenBalance || 0n)).toFixed(4)}
              <span className="font-bold ml-1">{yourTokenSymbol}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            Vendor eth balance: {Number(formatEther(vendorEthBalance?.value || 0n)).toFixed(4)}
            <span className="font-bold ml-1">ETH</span>
  </div>*/}
        </div>

        {/* Buy Tokens */}
        {/*<div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 bg-base-100 shadow-lg shadow-secondary border-8 border-secondary rounded-xl p-6 mt-8 w-full max-w-lg">
          <div className="text-xl">Buy tokens</div>
          <div>{tokensPerEth?.toString() || 0} tokens per ETH</div>

          <div className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <IntegerInput
              placeholder="amount of tokens to buy"
              value={tokensToBuy.toString()}
              onChange={value => setTokensToBuy(value)}
              disableMultiplyBy1e18
            />
          </div>

          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary mt-2"
            onClick={async () => {
              try {
                await writeVendorAsync({ functionName: "buyTokens", value: getTokenPrice(tokensToBuy, tokensPerEth) });
              } catch (err) {
                console.error("Error calling buyTokens function");
              }
            }}
          >
            Buy Tokens
          </button>
          </div>*/}

        {!!yourTokenBalance && (
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 bg-base-100 shadow-lg shadow-secondary border-8 border-secondary rounded-xl p-6 mt-8 w-full max-w-lg">
            <div className="text-xl">Transfer tokens</div>
            <div className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-2">
              <AddressInput placeholder="to address" value={toAddress} onChange={value => setToAddress(value)} />
              <IntegerInput
                placeholder="amount of tokens to send"
                value={tokensToSend}
                onChange={value => setTokensToSend(value as string)}
                disableMultiplyBy1e18
              />
            </div>

            <button
              className="btn btn-secondary"
              onClick={async () => {
                try {
                  await writeYourTokenAsync({
                    functionName: "transfer",
                    args: [toAddress, multiplyTo1e18(tokensToSend)],
                  });
                } catch (err) {
                  console.error("Error calling transfer function");
                }
              }}
            >
              Send Tokens
            </button>
          </div>
        )}

        {/* Sell Tokens */}
        {/* {!!yourTokenBalance && (
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 bg-base-100 shadow-lg shadow-secondary border-8 border-secondary rounded-xl p-6 mt-8 w-full max-w-lg">
            <div className="text-xl">Sell tokens</div>
            <div>{tokensPerEth?.toString() || 0} tokens per ETH</div>

            <div className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-2">
              <IntegerInput
                placeholder="amount of tokens to sell"
                value={tokensToSell}
                onChange={value => setTokensToSell(value as string)}
                disabled={isApproved}
                disableMultiplyBy1e18
              />
            </div>

            <div className="flex gap-4">
              <button
                className={`btn ${isApproved ? "btn-disabled" : "btn-secondary"}`}
                onClick={async () => {
                  try {
                    await writeYourTokenAsync({
                      functionName: "approve",
                      args: [vendorContractData?.address, multiplyTo1e18(tokensToSell)],
                    });
                    setIsApproved(true);
                  } catch (err) {
                    console.error("Error calling approve function");
                  }
                }}
              >
                Approve Tokens
              </button>

              <button
                className={`btn ${isApproved ? "btn-secondary" : "btn-disabled"}`}
                onClick={async () => {
                  try {
                    await writeVendorAsync({ functionName: "sellTokens", args: [multiplyTo1e18(tokensToSell)] });
                    setIsApproved(false);
                  } catch (err) {
                    console.error("Error calling sellTokens function");
                  }
                }}
              >
                Sell Tokens
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )} */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TokenVendor;


I've tried to solve it with uncommenting the pats on the page.tsx file but it didn't workout. Also I am not very sure that I uncommented right parts of the code.
